# Вывод из JS в PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Есть код в PHP и надо в него вывести из JS, вот пример:

```
    <script>
        var lkdkljgf = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
    </script>
$perfff = "СЮДА_ВЫВЕСТИ_ИЗ_JS";
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE id='$perfff '");
```

Как-то надо вывести из JS.
Никак не могу понять, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что js работаете на клиенте, а php на сервере?

Comment: В запросе у меня стоит вывод по `$_GET[]`, переход на эту страницу через `history.pushState(null, null, newurl);`, URL меняется визуально, соответственно в _GET тоже ни чего не обновляется. Мне и надо как-то сделать так, чтобы получить из URL этот самый параметр

Answer (score 0):

```
some.php:

if($_GET['from_js_to_php']) {
    $perfff = $_GET['from_js_to_php'];
}

<script>
    var toPhpVar = "some very important here";
    window.location.href = window.location.href + "?from_js_to_php=" + encodeURI(toPhpVar); 
</script>
```